# Providing correct path for React-PDF

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I'm trying to use React-PDF to display a pdf within my component but cannot figure out how to provide it with the correct path for my pdf.
my file is located under ReactApp/public/pdf/myPdf.pdf

this is where I'm putting my path:

```
<Document
     file={filepath}
>
</Document>
```

So far i tried the following without luck:

pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

/pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

./pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

../pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

%PUBLIC_URL%/pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

I can, however load the file by using:

localhost:61631/pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

Comment: check this comment: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/188#issuecomment-383375013 that might help you

Comment: according to the comment this should have worked: pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf ?

Comment: have you tried import a PDF file as a module?

Comment: I'm getting the following trying to import as module: Module not found: Can't resolve '../public/pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf' in

Comment: are you sure that relative path: `../public/pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf` is the right one?

Comment: well, i assume it is since i can load localhost:61631/pdf/GenericCustomerConsentAgreement.pdf

Comment: I mean relative path from the folder you are currently inside